# What's the meaning of this long TOEFL sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

There's a text from one of the TOEFL exams:

> Wildman and Niles observed that systematic reflection on teaching
> required a sound ability to understand classroom events in an
> objective manner. They describe the initial understanding in the
> teachers with whom they were working as being “utilitarian … and not
> rich or detailed enough to drive systematic reflection.”

I can't understand the meaning of the second sentence: "They describe ... ."
what does "in the teachers" mean?
what does "drive systematic reflection" mean?

Answer (score 1):

"They describe the initial understanding in the teachers..."

means

"They tell us that the knowledge the teachers possessed at the beginning..."

and

"...drive systematic reflection"

means

"push forward the process of a wide range of reconsidering on this topic"

"drive" = "move forward in an externally motivated manner", like a car driving someone to a destination

Answer (score 1):

They observe that fellow teachers lack in deep comprehension of classroom events. Such teachers adopt a pragmatic approach to teaching, and don't consider single events as part of a complex process.
Systematic reflection is a learning procedure during which learners comprehensively analyze their behaviour and evaluate the contribution of its components to performance outcomes.